Webcam on dell XPS 13 not working
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 on a dell XPS 13 9315 and suddenly started having issues with my webcam.
The camera does not seem to turn on and just shows black in each application I try (chrome, cheese, kamoso, zoom). Previously, when the camera was wokring, the light next to it would come on. Now the light never comes on.
v4l2-ctl recognized Intel MIPI Camera as well as some ipu6 devices:
sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices
[sudo] password for benc: 
ipu6 (PCI:pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/video6
    /dev/video7
    /dev/video8

ipu6 (pci:pci0000:00):
    /dev/media0

Intel MIPI Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

The output of lsusb does not seem to recognize the camera:
sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:63ac Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Following other answers, I made sure that libcamhal-ipu6ep0 is installed properly. This did not seem to make any difference.

Can't give you sources - but I read somewhere a rollback to 22.04.3 (with linux 6.2) solved the issue for some people.
It's a kernel/driver thing, so you might want to look into this direction, if a downgrade did not sove your problem.
